# check if object is a mongo cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a method in which I want to either receive a list or a mongo cursor and react to that, for example:

```
createFromTemplate: function(template) {
  var iter;
  if(template instanceof Mongo.Cursor) {
    iter = template.fetch();
  } else if(template instanceof Array) {
    iter = template;
  } else {
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Template must be a Cursor or Array');
  }
}
```

However, it seems to return false when I don't expect it

```
> var p = PageTemplates.find();  // as a mongo cursor
> var pArray = p.fetch();        // as an array
> Object.prototype.toString.call(p);
[object Object]
> typeof p
Object
> p instanceof Mongo.Cursor
false
```

How can I tell if an object is a Mongo cursor?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `instanceof Mongo.Collection.Cursor` (not `Mongo.Cursor`).  From my console:

```
> a = Meteor.users.find()
<- LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: Minimongo.Matcher, skip: undefined…}
> a instanceof Mongo.Collection.Cursor
<- true
```